# How to place an image beside text? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have a paragraph that I have formated the right margin to leave room for an image beside. How would I place the image there? Because I have the right margin set it is not allowing me to place the image directly beside it? Is there a tag I can use? I have attached an image below.

[This is a picture of the paragraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SgMJ.png)

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLGkM.png)

Comment: Can you post some HTML and CSS?

Comment: you could use the :after selector

Comment: Please show the **essential** code to reproduce your problem. Your question  needs more details to be answered. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please consider posting your code so that we can point out to you what should be done to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS property `display: inline-block` and create 2 different div for image and paragraph. Set width of div according to your need as in example I used 30% and 70% for image and paragraph respectively.

```html
    <style>
        div{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .image{
            width: 30%;
        }
        .paragraph{
            width: 70%;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <div class="image">
           <img src="image.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
            your paragraph goes here.
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can also use bootstrap grid basic to do this. Bootstrap has provided predefined classes for this work.